# Disable drag drop record in kanban odoo12

Tags: xml, security, odoo, odoo-12, kanban

i want the user to only view the opportunities by its stages in kanban view and not to change the stages ? 
And disable sorting columns (stages) 
All solutions i found for other versions 7 , 10 and 13 not odoo version12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [kanban view](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html#kanban) documentation, to disable editing stages you can set `group_edit` option to `false` on `kanban` tag.

```
<kanban ... group_edit="false">
```

To disable column sorting I did not find an option, it seems that the renderer (`_renderGrouped`) only checks if the stage field is of type `many2one`, so I added a new option to enable or disable column sorting.

```
var KanbanRenderer = require('web.KanbanRenderer');

KanbanRenderer.include({

    _setState: function (state) {
        var self = this;
        this._super(state);
        if (this.arch.attrs.sortable) {
            this.columnOptions = _.extend(self.columnOptions, {
                sortable: this.arch.attrs.sortable === 'true',
            });
        }

        if (this.arch.attrs.disable_drag_drop_record) {
            if (this.arch.attrs.disable_drag_drop_record=='true') {
                this.columnOptions.draggable = false;
            }
        }
    },

    _renderGrouped: function (fragment) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        if (this.columnOptions.sortable===false) {
            // remove previous sorting
            this.$el.sortable('destroy');
        }
    },

});
```

Set `sortable` attribute to `false` in kanban view:

```
<kanban ... sortable="false" disable_drag_drop_record="true">
```

Comment: i added ```<attribute name="group_edit">false</attribute>``` it just disable editing record in kanban view but can't disable drag and drop cards in kanban view ..
i added your js code and include it's file in template web.assets_backend but has no effect

Comment: Did you add the `sortable` attribute?

Comment: yes ```<attribute name="sortable">false</attribute>``` but still doesn't work
i found a solution
i guess you forgot to add :
```
odoo.define('kanban_draggable.kanban_column',function(require){
"use strict";
```
it works
[solution](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/kanban_draggable/?fbclid=IwAR0oJ9W2hM1xKqNVWuYnKbJNxpjyDMgbgSE2ddztjv4usIKYWkV913UtbCI)

Comment: Of course, I omit to add it. I added just the relevant part.

Comment: thanks again first time i didn't understand your answer because i am newbie odoo developer ... thanks again

Comment: I am glad to help you. Think to check the accepted-answer flag so future users will trust it.

Comment: yes also add disable drag and drop
`

var drag_drop = true;
        if (arch.attrs.disable_drag_drop_record) {
            if (arch.attrs.disable_drag_drop_record=='true') {
                this.columnOptions.draggable = false;
            }
        }
`

Comment: Added `disable_drag_drop_record` option.

Answer (score 0):

you can stop that by modifying the attribute of stage_id for example

```
<field name="stage_id" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
</field>
```